# How to edit yaml path for azure devops build pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I had a project in VSTS with a build defined by a yaml file and it was working great.

Then I moved the yaml file in my repo to a different folder.
(Initially the folder was \build, but after the refactoring I called it \templates)

Now build pipeline is not working because it cannot find the yaml file. And if I click "Edit" button it gets me to the yaml editing, not the pipeline settings.

How to update the yaml path without deleting the pipeline and creating a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And found it.

**Updated answer**

Go to your build pipeline -> Edit (it will take you to yaml editing screen) -> "..." button -> Settings:

[image]

Which will open "Pipeline Settings":
[image]

**Old answer**

(Just for historical reasons I will keep the old answer - maybe it will be reverted back again?)

For someone who is looking for the same thing - when you go to edit mode there is a small hyperlink under "Docs" and "Run" buttons - "Edit in the visual designer"

[image]

Comment: Since you already answer your own question, please mark your own answer as answer, then.

Comment: I'm totally not seeing this.  Can you capture a larger screenshot or provide any menu navigation pointers to how to get to this?  Are there any dependencies that you are aware of that must be fulfilled before this option shows up?

Comment: @JonathanB. Yup, it was changed. Updated the answer